# Swift Tab Bar Disappears From Segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, tabbar

My first view controller has a tab bar on the bottom. There is a button on this first view controller that leads to another view controller. On the second view controller it has a back button that leads back to the first view controller. But once I hit the back button to go back to the first view controller, the tab bar is disappearing. I'm not sure how to get the tab bar to show up after I return.

Comment: Can you post your Storyboard setup? My guess is your nav controllers are fucky

Comment: Post you backButton and segue codes